# Hacer Consulta de Insertar Solo Con Acceder en MYSQL y PHP

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, phpmyadmin, php5

Hola quisiera saber si es posible insertar un registro en una tabla (usuario_cand) solo con acceder con usuario y contraseña. En otras palabra que yo acceda desde un form_login que me pida usuario y contraseña y si el usuario no había accedido antes le permite acceder a otra pagina(form_accedio) pero se registre su ingreso en la tabla (usuario_cand)de la bd mysql y si ya habia accedido le diga no puede volver a ingresar.

YA puedo mostrar si puedo Acceder o No.... pero no logro ingresar que se registre el acceso de este usuario en la tabla  usuario_cand Usuario que previamente esta almacenado en la tabla usuario.

```
<?php
    include ("conexion.php"); 
    $id_usuario= @$_POST['id_usuario']; 
    $verificar= "SELECT id_usuario FROM usuario_aspirante WHERE id_usuario='$id_usuario'"; 
    $resultado = mysqli_query($conexion, $verificar);
    $filas = mysqli_num_rows($resultado); 
    if($filas==0){ 
        echo "Puede acceder"; 
        //header("location:form_accedio.php"); 
    }
    else{ 
        echo "<script> alert('Ya Habias Accedido...puede volver a ingresar '); 
        window.location='index.php'; </script>"; 
    } 
?>
```

Comment: Te invito a revisar [ask], para que formules mejor tu pregunta. Podrías agregar algo del código que tienes hasta ahora?

Comment: Tienes un campo en la tabla usuario_aspirante para saber si acceso o no? o tienes otra tabla para saber si ya había entrado? Porque no has puesto la consulta que implementas para saber actualizar el status

Comment: @Mundoco Ya actualice la pregunta y este es el código que tengo hasta ahora.... no logro insertar el registro en la tabla usuario_cand solo con acceder desde el form login

Answer (score 0):

Hace más o menos un mes hice esto... Te lo he comentado, ¡espero que te sirva!

```
<?php
    //defino una variable tipo boolean (true o false)
    $t_f = false; 

    //defino una variable que después usaré
    $id;

    //con la función isset miro si el usuario ha introducido algún valor
    if (isset($_POST['user']) && isset($_POST['password'])) {

      //Descarto que el valor que haya introducido el usuario esté en blaco
      if ($_POST['user'] && $_POST['password']) {


       //si el usuario ha introducido algo en los input de usuario y password, defino la 
       //variable $conn donde hago la conexión a la BBDD
        $conn = pg_pconnect("host=localhost port=5432 dbname=base_de_datos user=postgres password=1234");

        //en caso que la conexión a la BBDD falle saldrá el siguiente error
        if (!$conn) {
          echo "Ocurrió un error.\n";
          exit;
        }

        //Guardo en una variable todos los valores de la tabla usuario
        $result = pg_query($conn, "select * from usuari");

        //Si no hay valores en la tabla usuarios, sale el siguiente error
        if (!$result) {
          echo "Ocurrió un error.\n";
          exit;
        }

        //Leo linea por linea la variable $result y esta linea se guarda en una variable 
        //temporal llamada $row
        while ($row = pg_fetch_row($result)) {

    //Si el usuario de la base de datos ($row[1]) coincide con el usuario ($_POST['user'])
    //Si el usuario de la base de datos ($row[4]) coincide con el usuario 
    //($_POST['password'])
    //$t_f que antes era false, ahora es true
          //la variable tipo booleana inicializada al principio pasa a ser true
          if ($row[1] == $_POST['user'] && $row[4] == $_POST['password']) {
            $id = $row[0];
            $t_f = true;

          }
        }

        //Si la variable booleana inicializada al principio es true, se hace el insert en 
        //la base de datos
        if ($t_f) {
          $nombre_host = gethostbyaddr($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);

          //Variable donde guardo la consulta
          $insert = "insert into usuari_conectat values (".$id.",'".$nombre_host."')";

          //Ejecuta la consulta
          pg_query($conn, $insert);
        }else{
          echo "ERROR";
        }
      }else{
        echo "NO DEIXIS RES EN BLANC";
      }
    }

     ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

No veo el código extra que comentas, yo edité tu pregunta poniendo el código que habías puesto en el comentario.

Tengo algunas dudas sobre los datos de acceso al usuario están en la tabla usuario_aspirante o ¿los llamas de otra tabla? después ves si el usuario es aspirante y por ultimo si ya es candidato?

Yo lo que haria es tener una sola tabla usuario y poner un campo que diga que tipo de usuario es: aspirante o candidato.

Si es aspirante si podría acceder a la pagina form_accedio.php e inmediatamente cambiar el estatus a candidato, para que ya no pueda volver a entrar.

Pero creo que lo que quieres es lo siguiente:

```
<?php
    include ("conexion.php"); 
    $id_usuario= @$_POST['id_usuario']; 
    $verificar= "SELECT id_usuario FROM usuario_aspirante WHERE id_usuario='$id_usuario'"; 
    $resultado = mysqli_query($conexion, $verificar);
    $filas = mysqli_num_rows($resultado); 
    if($filas==0){
         $insert = "INSERT INTO usuario_cand (id_usuario, usuario, password) VALUES ('$id_usuario', '$_POST['usuario']', '$_POST['password']')";
        mysqli_query($conexion, $insert);
        echo "Puede acceder"; 
        //header("location:form_accedio.php"); 
    }
    else{ 
        echo "<script> alert('Ya Habias Accedido...puede volver a ingresar '); 
        window.location='index.php'; </script>"; 
    } 
?>
```

Comment: yo los llamo de la tabla usuario que tiene los campos id_usuario,nombre,usuario,clave   lo otro es que necesito que al ingresar con ese usuario y clave se pueda insertar un registro con el id_usuario que acabo de entrar para que ya no pueda seguir ingresando pero que el registro se haga en la tabla usuario_cand que solo tiene los campos (id_usuario, id_candidato) eso es lo que quiero que se registre cada acceso ahí. Sí se podrá hacer esto...yo puedo hacer el voto y demas pero no logro controlar los accesos y asi podrian hacer cada usuario múltiples votos y se me ocurre asi evitarlo